# Secure password storing while authenticating to JIRA via SOAP service

Tags: java, security, soap, passwords, jira

I am writing an application, in Java, which needs to log in to a remote SOAP service (JIRA) prior to calling methods on that service.

I have looked at examples of how to do this, for example http://www.j-tricks.com/1/post/2010/8/jira-soap-client.html, however I am concerned that I need to put the password in memory at some point.

I've read that I should store the password as a char[] but still, I'm concerned about storing the password in the clear at all.

How should I store the password used by my client to log into the SOAP service?  And how should I read it and pass it to JIRA?

*EDIT*
This application will be using Spring so it's likely the password would be stored in the bean configuration file rather than in the code.

Comment: An excellent question. I've tried to do that myself, but I had to eventually give it up due to lack of time. I'm curious if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP login method returns a string token you can use for the session, so there's no need to store the password in memory after using it. But I think you're talking about longer term usage. Applications will usually have a configuration page to allow a more permanent authentication to be set up, and then require a password to be entered each time that connection is reconfigured.

Comment: Good point - once the authentication token is obtained, I can wipe the password string.  However the application is a batch process which will need to authenticate with JIRA each time it starts (typically nightly).  So there is no end-user configuration.  My concern is that I don't particularly like leaving the password in the source code or Spring config file at all.

Comment: That would explain why your reference recommends a char[] ... once the password finds its way into an immutable String object, it can't be altered until it is garbage collected.

Comment: @phatfingers which is generally never due to the string pool

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I decided on eventually.

First, some clarifications.

- The password is encrypted and stored in a database.
- The password is statically populated (by the DBA).
- This is an exercise in encryption and decryption, therefore hashing algorithms, such as MD5 are not applicable.

I looked into ways of encrypting in SQL and decrypting in Java, but none were particularly good.  Therefore I decided upon the following approach.

- When the DBA populates the password, they run the DBMS-specific encryption method (e.g. MySQL's encrypt) when entering the password (e.g. insert into creds(user,password) values ('bob',encrypt('password'));
- The SQL to retreive the password, passed to the spring application as a property, includes the decryption (e.g. select user,decrypt(password) from creds).

Other than that, this is an exercise in user management and locking down the database.  E.g. only certain people (DBAs) get full access and the application uses a read-only user.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.